# Laravel 10 - Vue Vite works in localhost but not in Production

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am getting a very weird issue in my code. I am using:

- Laravel 10.
- Vue 3 Vite.
- Php 8.2
- The auth is api token with sactum... NO the spa

So my login code is:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $token = Auth::user()->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => [
                'user' => Auth::user(),
                'token' => $token
            ]
        ], 200);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Invalid credentials'
    ], 401);
}
```

My config/sactum.php code:

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    '%s%s',
    'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,example.test,paneldecontrolem.cl',
    Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
))),
```

I am getting the token I already checked it.

How I said in localhost worked perfect but when I upload my code to production, I login perfectly but when I start to use the endpoints I start to receive 401 so If I use this vue code:

```
async getData() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.isLoading = true;
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

        try {
            const response = await axios.get(
                "https://paneldecontrolem.cl/api/alliance/",
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                        accept: "application/json",
                    },
                }
            );

            this.posts = response.data.data;
            this.loading = false;
            this.isLoading = false;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error al obtener la lista de alianzas:", error);
        }
    },
```

I receive 401 I have tried all, I have read different posts but they did not work to me.. so I wonder what could it be??  Thanks!

Comment: Could you check if the ```$credentials``` variable is actually getting data from the request object in production. Add a ```Log::info```, test it in production, and check your log file to see what happens.

Comment: Hi @Zxeenu [2023-12-01 19:58:44] local.INFO: array (
  'email' => 'administrator@wewew.cl',
  'password' => '232323232323',
)  
[2023-12-01 19:58:45] local.INFO: 23|mcAaQav98hFPbtY4JCX22212VzyTG1HJPPb129d610  
[2023-12-01 19:58:45] local.INFO: {"id":1,"name":"Administrator","email":"administrator@232323.cl","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2023-12-01T08:37:40.000000Z","updated_at":"2023-12-01T08:37:40.000000Z"}  Yes I received it

Comment: Just a note, in your sanctum config there is a "," missing in the sprintf function between the two %s

Comment: please make sure to add new information/code to your question with the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77587719/edit) feature. It is hard to read unformatted code in comments.